# Blocking read from std::ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am reading from a pipe (Linux) or a pipe-like device object (Windows) using `std::ifstream::read`. However, when there is no more data, `read` reads 0 bytes and sets `EOF`. Is there a way to make a blocking read from an `ifstream`, such that it only returns when there is some more data?

I'd rather not busy wait for the `EOF` flag to clear.

If it is not possible with the C++ standard library, what is the closest other option? Can I do it in plain C, or do I have to resort to operating system specific APIs?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `std` is very poor on any non-algorithmic functionality, like IO. You always have to rely on 3rd-party solutions. Fortunately, there is Boost and, if you do not mind, I will suggest to use it to reduce OS specific code.

```
    namespace bs = boost::iostreams;
    int fd; // Create, for example, Posix file descriptor and specify necessary flags for it.
    bs::file_descriptor_source fds(fd);
    bs::stream<bs::file_descriptor_source> stream(fds);
    // Work with the stream as it is std stream
```

In this small example I use [Boost IO Streams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) and specifically [`file_descriptor_source`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/file_descriptor.html) that works as an underlying stream device and hides Windows or Posix specific pipe inside. The pipe you open yourself, so you can configure the pipe as you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Unfortunately, installing Boost on Windows is just about as complicated as just writing it all in WinApi to begin with ;-).

Comment: If you are using MinGW you can use `packman` to install it based on this package repository [Alexpux Packages](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages).

Comment: And for Visual Studio  there are [these binaries](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.64.0/)

Answer (score 1):

well there seems no way to do a blocking read. clearing the error bit will not help. Only a re-open of the fifo like in this example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rc=0;
    enum FATAL {ERR_ARGV,ERR_OPEN_FILE};
    try
    {
            if( argv[1] == NULL) throw ERR_ARGV;
            std::ifstream fifo;

            while(1)
            {
                    fifo.open(argv[1],std::ifstream::in);
                    if( !fifo.is_open() ) throw ERR_OPEN_FILE;

                    std::string line;
                    while(std::getline(fifo,line))
                    {
                            std::cout << line << "\n"; fflush(stdout);
                    }
                    fifo.close();
            }
            // never should come here
    }
    catch(FATAL e)
    {
            rc=e;
            switch(e)
            {
            case ERR_ARGV:
                    std::cerr << "ERROR: argument 1 should be a fifo file name\n";
                    break;
            case ERR_OPEN_FILE:
                    std::cerr << "ERROR: unabel to open file " << argv[1] << "\n";
                    break;
            }
    }
    return(rc);
}
```

I have tested this code and it works to do an endless read from a fifo.

Comment: What do you mean with "clearing the error bit will not help"? I can call `input.clear()` fine - however afterwards I can't read from it, the next read attempt will set the EOF bit again. Is that normal? ... Your solution sounds good, however my server resets it's state currently when the pipe is closed, and I would have to change that first.

Comment: yes, this seems to be normal. the point is that you can not reset state in the way that std::getline() or other read function will block again, like it does after opening the fifo :( Well, yes also the other end of the pipe should do a re-open (you server in that case).